# Rails + Turbo broadcast_replace_later

Tags: sidekiq, broadcast, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo-frames

Help with Turbo Streams & Sidekiq.

Example File with code execution here: https://github.com/dostaglou/Basket/blob/main/app/models/basket.rb

I am working on an app and I am trying to use turbo_stream_from. Right now the code is using a callback to execute a synchronous stream update ( instance.broadcast_replace_to(instance) ). I would like to transform this into an asynchronous execution using either broadcast_replace_later_to or taking the current method and slapping it into a Job that has perform_later called on it.
However, the moment I move this to an asynchronous execution it stops working. I am not sure why and wondered if anyone might have insights into what I should check for.

So far the only thing I have seen that is different in their executions from the server logs is that the synchronous version has an entry that says `Turbo::StreamsChannel transmitting "--html--" (via streamed from --channel id--". I am not sure if this is significant

For the job execution, I have also added `include Turbo::StreamsHelper` and `include ActionView::RecordIdentifier` thinking this might be important but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.